# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I am using hibernate 3.6.7 to do mapping. I set the connection part as static.
I need the service program runs forever, and another service will call some methods of this service to query database.
When I leave the service running, the first day it works well but when I call it the next day, it gives:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2545)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at com.myCompany.Query.myMethod(Query.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.ebayopensource.ginger.server.internal.container.MessageProcessor.processRequest(MessageProcessor.java:93)
    at org.ebayopensource.ginger.server.container.GingerServletShell.service(GingerServletShell.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:864)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:783)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1700)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
```

It seems the connection gets closed. 
Could anyone please give me some suggestion?

Thank you very much:)

Comment: How did you solved? I use hiberante query to save objects and sometimes I got the same error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like either the database has closed the connection or some network device has terminated the socket.  There are many ways you can work around this problem:

1. You can issue some sort of "keep alive" type of query (ex: SELECT 1) on the connection every so often to keep it alive.  This assumes that it got closed because it was idle.
2. You can re-open the connection every so often.
3. If you get a connect closed exception then you can just reopen the connection.  Duh.
4. You can use a connection pool which can do the keep-alive and the reconnection for you.  [Apache's DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) is a favorite of many.

I recommend the last one.  You would use [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) something like:

```
BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
ds.setUsername("scott");
ds.setPassword("tiger");
ds.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1"); // this is database specific
ds.setTestWhileIdle(true); // test the connections every so often
ds.setUrl(connectURI);
...
while (!shutdown) {
    Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ...
    stmt.close();
    // this returns the connection back to the pool instead of really closing
    // the connection
    conn.close();
}
```

So instead of passing around a `Connection` you pass around the `BasicDataSource` and call `getConnection()` when you need the connection and `conn.close()` when you are done with it.  The pool does all of the validation work, etc.  It also will allow multiple threads to use the database.

Hope this helps.

---

**Edit:**  You also cannot hold a [hibernate session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html) open for a long time.  To show you how short lived the session is supposed to be, I'll quote from the docs:

> The lifecycle of a Session is bounded by the beginning and end of a logical transaction. (Long transactions might span several database transactions.)

A session holds a database connection so you never want to keep it around for any length of time.  You should do a couple of database requests (like a single web request with queries and updates) and then close the session so the underlying database connection can be returned to the pool.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried to have a live thread running and do query, but it doesn't work. I have to close hibernate session every time. Only this way works.

Comment: Oh.  I didn't realize you were holding a hibernate session open the entire time.  That's really bad form.  You should be closing that after your database pass otherwise it will be stuck to a particular connection forever.

Comment: Hi, I use JPARepository to save a massive number of object and sometimes I got this error, do you know how can I solve it?

Comment: I have some work arounds in my answer @Robs.

Answer (score 3):

That maybe the structure of the JAVA Model is changed,but the DB table update incorrect!     what make the Model and the DB table are not correspondence completely.
You can do like this:

- drop the old table
- restart the project to rebuild the table

Answer (score 0):

Recently I encountered this error in SpringBoot project.

Reason: Entity class and their respective data in Table had mismatched types. In my case one of the fields which was LocalDate type had value "0000-00-00".

Solution:

- In case you are building a new project, drop the old table and restart the project to rebuild the table.
- In case your project is old and you do not want to let go of your data, inspect the database table and fix the corresponding value manually.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting exactly same error when using native Update query.

I resolved this error by using @Modifying (pkg: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying) as well as @Transactional annotation (pkg: javax.transaction.Transactional) in repository method.
If we are using Insert, Update, Delete query then @Modifying is required in addition to @Transactional.

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value="Update TBL_EMPLOYEE SET STATUS = :status where ID = :id", nativeQuery = true)
void updateEmployee(@Param("status") String status, @Param("id") String id)
```