# usage of different Hibernate Config files for defining a datasource

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, datasource

I am struggling with four configuration file in my hibernate project on tomcat ( web.xml , context.xml, hibernate.cfg.xml and persistence.xml) to define my data source to H2 database. The usage of these four configuration file in defining a data source is not clear for me.

For example shoud I define usename and password in my persistence.xml properties or in context.xml. I found different samples that defines in different way.

Here is my setting for these file, which lead me to the following exception

```
(javax.persistence.PersistenceException) javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
```

it caused by this nested exception

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: 
Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
```

My web.xml

```
<env-entry>
  <env-entry-name>name</env-entry-name>
  <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
  <env-entry-value>Tomcat</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>

 <listener>
    <description>PersistenceListener</description>
    <listener-class>test.sample.raindance.hibernate.PersistenceListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/MyApp</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Context.xml

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/">
<Resource
name="jdbc/MyApp" 
auth="Container" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
username="sa" 
password="" 
driverClassName="org.h2.Driver" 
url="jdbc:h2:~/test;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE" 
maxActive="8" 
maxIdle="4" 
maxWait="10000"/>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
 <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

<property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</property>

<property name="connection.datasource">java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyApp</property>

<!-- Mapping files -->

<mapping class="test.sample.raindance.hibernate.Game"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

persistence.xml

```
 <persistence-unit name="hibernate-test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyApp</non-jta-data-source>

        <class>test.sample.raindance.hibernate.Game</class>
        <properties>


<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyApp"/>
<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value ="true"/>

<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
<!-- <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/> -->
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
<property name="connection.autocommit" value="false"/>  

    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What am doing wrong with these settings! may be I am writing wrong property or in wrong setting file.

Thanks for any help

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900221/org-hibernate-exception-genericjdbcexception-could-not-execute-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined my data source for my hibernate application for tomcat 7 in this way:

use context.xml to define datasource , database driver, username and password and so on. It should be placed in /META-INF/context.xml in your webrAchive

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context antiJARLocking="true"  path="/MyApp">
<Resource
name="jdbc/MyApp" 
auth="Container" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
username="sa" 
password="" 
driverClassName="org.h2.Driver" 
url="jdbc:h2:~/test;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE"    
maxActive="8" 
maxIdle="4" 
maxWait="10000"/>     
</Context>
```

use web.xml to introduce your datasource to your web.xml with resource-ref tag.It should be placed in /WEB-INF/web.xml in your webrAchive

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

   <env-entry>
      <env-entry-name>name</env-entry-name>
      <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
      <env-entry-value>Tomcat</env-entry-value>
   </env-entry>

   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
   </listener>

     <listener>
        <description>PersistenceListener</description>
        <listener-class>test.sample.raindance.hibernate.PersistenceListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/MyApp</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

till this point, all settings is related to your container and hibernate don't know anything about this connection. persistence.xml will introduce this connection to the hibernate engine.It should be placed in /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml in your webrAchive

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
     <persistence-unit name="hibernate-test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/MyApp</non-jta-data-source>

        <class>test.sample.raindance.hibernate.Game</class>
        <properties>


 <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value ="true"/>

<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
 <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
<property name="connection.autocommit" value="false"/>   
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

there is no need for hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 0):

Leave it in the context file. Usernames and passwords are not the concern of your persistence layer or your web app. Your web app is only really concerned with having a resource.

That way authentication is kept with your datasource which, in my mind, makes much mores sense.