# Closed connection with ORMLite and MySql

Tags: mysql, spring, ormlite

I have ORMLite configured like in sample 7 of ORMLite docs, but after a while I get Connection closed error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed
at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource.getReadWriteConnection   (JdbcConnectionSource.java:177)
at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource.getReadOnlyConnection(JdbcConnectionSource.java:168)
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:228)
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:181)
at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.query(BaseDaoImpl.java:263)
at com.tube.auction.db.DbFacade.createOrUpdateUser(DbFacade.java:265)
```

I use only dao beans in code.

```
<bean id="databaseUrl" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/auction" />
</bean>

<bean id="connectionSource" class="com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource" init-method="initialize">
    <property name="url" ref="databaseUrl" />        
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
<bean id="userDao" class="com.j256.ormlite.spring.DaoFactory" factory-method="createDao">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="connectionSource" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="com.tube.auction.dto.User" />
</bean>
```

How do I handle Connection closed issues? I can't see any way to force connection restart
For example
Note that isOpen() for dao.connection [returns true](http://screenshots.ryotsuke.ru/scr_84b6d6e1701c.png)

```
-- 1. Can i test connection here and restart it? How? Code snippet?
try {
    userDao.queryForId(someUserId);
} catch(SQLException ex) {
   if(is this connection closed?) {
       -- 2. What should I do here to restart connection?
   }
}
```

Comment: Max The Cat how did you exactly solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

`JdbcConnectionSource` does not have an internal keep-alive mechanism.   `JdbcPooledConnectionSource` spawns an internal thread to perform keep alive tests.  This solved the problem for me.

Try changing the bean connection source to use `JdbcPooledConnectionSource`, like this:

```
<bean id="connectionSource" class="com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcPooledConnectionSource" init-method="initialize">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a FAQ.  After a while the server may close a database connection because it has not been used in a while or for some other reason.

I talk about the ways to keep a connection open in this answer here:

> [org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900221/org-hibernate-exception-genericjdbcexception-could-not-execute-query/8901922#8901922)

To quote, there are many ways you can work around this problem:

1. You can issue some sort of "keep alive" type of query (ex: SELECT 1) on the connection every so often to keep it alive.  This assumes that it got closed because it was idle.  You could use a ORMLite "raw query" for this.
2. You can re-open the connection every so often.  With ORMLite, this depends on what sort of connection source you are using.
3. If you get a connect closed exception then you can just reopen the connection.  Duh.
4. You can use a connection pool which can do the keep-alive and the reconnection for you.  [Apache's DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) and [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) are two of my favorites of many.  They work with ORMLite.

See my answer for more details.

Comment: Good ideas, however, none actually address the question.  The question specifically mentions how to do it in ORMLite.

Comment: ORMlite works with DBCP and other connection pool libraries @MCToon.   That's the best answer.